# list object has no attribute 'apply' even though it is no list

Tags: python, pandas

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=';', header=None, skiprows=1, engine='python', names=['I', 'II', 'III']))
df2["COMBINED"] = df2["I"].astype(str) + df2["II"].astype(str) + df2["III"].astype(str)

df2 = df2['COMBINED'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).str.lower()
df2 = [ nltk.word_tokenize( str(COMBINED) ) for COMBINED in df2 ]

a = df2.apply(set)
```

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=';', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['I', 'II', 'III']))
df2["COMBINED"] = df2["I"].astype(str) + df2["II"].astype(str) + df1["III"].astype(str)
df2["COMBINED"] = df1["COMBINED"].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df2 = df2.COMBINED.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x if item.lower() not in stop_words])
a = df2.apply(set)
```

**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'intersection'**

Anyone an idea how to get around those issues? I want to generate a dot product between two dataframes with strings, i.e., each row with each row of the other df.

Comment: Why don't you use scipy distance matrix function like `cdist` or `pdist`? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html

Comment: Because they aren't points but tokens. How would I write it for two dataframes? This only allows for one df

Comment: Could you kindly re-organize your code? What is `stop_words` and why `df2` is created before `df` while `df2` relies on `df` in `df2 = df.sentence.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)`?

Comment: It was a typo. This dataframe simply was there before because my first approach was a single row. stop_words are taken out because they add no context.

Comment: Hey @Ynjxsjmh do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `pd.DataFrame()` after `pd.read_csv()`, the return type of `pd.read_csv()` is already a dataframe.

```py
df2 = df2['COMBINED'].replace({'\$': '', ',': ''}, regex=True).str.lower()
# ^
# |
# Here df2 is a Series, from the original COMBINED column


df2 = [ nltk.word_tokenize( str(COMBINED) ) for COMBINED in df2 ]
# ^                                               ^
# |                                               |
# Here df2 is a list                            Each element in df2 Series

a = df2.apply(set)
```

List definitely doesn't have attribute `apply`.

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv("file.csv", delimiter=';', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['I', 'II', 'III'])
# ^
# |
# df2 has columns I, II, III

df2["COMBINED"] = df2["I"].astype(str) + df2["II"].astype(str) + df1["III"].astype(str)
# ^
# |
# You create a new column combined,
# df2 now has columns I, II, III, COMBINED

df2["COMBINED"] = df1["COMBINED"].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
# ^
# |
# Do operations on COMBINED column

df2 = df2.sentence.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
# ^
# |
# By using df2.sentence you are accessing sentence column,
# there is no sentence column, only columns I, II, III, COMBINED
```

Comment: Okay, I understand. The df2. sentence was a typo and it does not change the results. I did the merging in Excel and now have two nearly identical columns that I want to plot against each other. Still it does not work. How can I solve my problem? Both ways do not run completely.

Comment: **AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'apply'** if I do both dataframes with the same code, i.e.,

Comment: `df1['sentence'] = df1['sentence'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df1['sentence'] = df1['sentence'].str.replace('\d+', '')
df1 = df1.sentence.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: [item.lower() for item in x if item.lower() not in stop_words])`

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT It looks fine with me. `df1` is Series after `f1 = df1.sentence.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)`. Series has apply function. The error should be somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it's in the tokenize column now: `df1 = df1.all.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)`. But how if the other dataframe runs fine with it while having the same/similar data

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT What is `all` column in df2?

Comment: It is the same as 'COMBINED 'but I did it in Excel in case that would have caused issues.

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT You may need change it to another name, because dataframe has a `all` function. Or you can call it like `df1['all'].apply`.

Comment: Alright. Same line, different problem which I also encountered yesterday:                             **TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object** And it is certainly a string which does not look much different than the other frame but a bit longer and with numbers/ IDs

Comment: That might be an error given by `nltk.word_tokenize`, make sure you pass it the expected type.

Comment: Okay. I now tried it with the same dataframe twice, i.e., same input giving it a different name. Now it says **AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'intersection'** when I try to get the intersection:                                                                                               `a = df2.apply(set)
b = df1.apply(set)
c =  b.apply(lambda x : a.intersection(x))
len_a_b = b.apply(lambda x : len(x) +  len(a))
len_c  = c.apply(lambda x : len(x))
dict1 = {'length' : len_c / (len_a_b - len_c) , 'b' : b , 'c' : c}`

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT `a` is a Series, it certainly has no column `intersection`.

Comment: But why did it work when I used one series and one manually tokenized row of words? What do I need to get the intersection and how do I achieve it preparing the dataframes?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Ok. Well I now have the preparation done with the other df, too. I now just have to pass both df through my function which is determining the Jaccard Similarity between both.

Comment: Which data type has the attributes list AND intersection? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT Kindly go through [10 minutes to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html), then you won't have those questions.

Comment: Yes, I went through it but it did not answer this particular question directly. Would it be possible to tell me? I've got a bit time pressure, sorry.

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT *Which data type has the attributes list AND intersection?* By using `df.intersection` you are accessing column `intersection` in df. If there is no column `intersection`, it will raise error, no attribute `intersection`.

Comment: But isn't it created by `a = df2.apply(set)
b = df1.apply(set)
c =  b.apply(lambda x : a.intersection(x))` ? It says **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'** for `a = df2.apply(set)`

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT What is the result of `a.columns`?

Comment: It won't give me an output because it the line where a is created does not work

Comment: @SAPNONEXPERT By using `df2.apply(set)` what do you want to do?

Comment: Isn't that the foundation for my comparison via intersection? I need two sets of words which are then compared

Comment: What is `intersection`? A function from another library?

Comment: No, it is the normal mathematical operation. Like a Venn diagram. It shows me how many words are equal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231313/discussion-between-ynjxsjmh-and-sapnonexpert).